# I would like to show alphabets dynamically in the column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a sql Table. And I would like to show table data using select command.

```
select * from table1
```

Now i would like to show one more column which show alphabets char.

```
select *, char(65) as alphabets from table1
```

but the result should be like

```
s.no.  table1Col    alphabets
1        data1         A
2        data2         B 
3        data3         C
```

Comment: If we generate characters from A to Z then it will fill 26 records what is the character for 27th record? or the alphabets have to be generated dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
create table #temp(col1 int,col2 char(10))

    insert into #temp values(1,'abile')
    insert into #temp values(2,'sbile')
    insert into #temp values(3,'rbile')

    Select A.*,char(64+A.rn) as Alphabets from
    (
    select *,row_number() over (order by col2) as rn from #temp) as A
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

select *, char(cast((90 - 65 )*rand() + 65 as integer)) as alphabets from table1